# Mongoskin, populate DBREF attribute

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoskin

I m actually facing a problem with mongoskin and referenced object :
- I have a user collection
- I have a typeuser collection
- user contain a ref on typeuser

I need to get my full user object, containing the user attributes AND the typeuser attributes too.

Is it possible to make it with the collection syntaxe :

```
collection(@collection).findOne {_id: new @objectId(@request.params.id)}, (err, result)
```

???

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

if you want all the attributes means use

> .populate('typeuser')

in your user.

Comment: It doesnt work with mongoskin, or with this syntax :/